# Limsup with a constant offset

Tags: calculus

**Question**
Given that $a_n$ is bounded, and $a$ is constant. We define $b_n=a_n-a$.

Is it always true that $\limsup(b_n)=\limsup(a_n)-a$?

**Thoughts**
I know that if $P_a, P_b$ are the sets of partial limits of $a_n, b_n$ then each member of $P_b$ equals some member in $P_a-a$. This makes me believe this statement is always true, but I don't know how to formalize it.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, it's true. $\lvert a_n - x\rvert < \varepsilon \iff \lvert b_n - (x-a)\rvert < \varepsilon$. So the set of limit points of $b_n$ is exactly the set of limit points of $a_n$ translated by $a$.